# Clear JSF session before navigating to a new portlet

Tags: jsf, portlet

In our application we have a portlet defined for each of the user tabs.

- We are using JSF 1.2 +Portlets.
- I want to clear the FacesContext Session managed beans when user
  navigates from one tab to another.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

- Is there any portlet unload function available where we can write
  code to remove session managed beans before user leaves the
  tab(portlet).

Comment: Are you sure your managed beans need to be @SessionScoped? In your scenario, it seems that view or conversation scope would fit much better.

Comment: we are using JSF 1.2 so I wont be able to use view scope thanks

Comment: Is CDI available to you? If so, it has Conversation Scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using JSF 1.2 and thus cannot take benefit of the new view scope which is designed for exactly this purpose, your best bet is to grab [MyFaces Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/index.html) or [MyFaces Orchestra](http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/index.html). You only need to put your "view" scoped beans back from the session scope into the request scope.

If you'd like to simulate the new JSF 2.0 view scope, i.e. the bean lives as long as you're interacting with the same view, then you need to add Tomahawk's [`<t:saveState>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_saveState.html) to the view referencing the request scoped bean.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.input}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
    <t:saveState value="#{bean}" />
</h:form>
```

If you'd like to simulate the new CDI conversation scope, which can span multiple views within the same browser tab, then you'd need to integrate Orchestra.